# Remove all characters from a string before/until a specific string variable occurs in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string, and I want to remove all the characters before another string variable using `.split()`. Does anyone know how to do it?

`'5+5 20-5 5.4 50/2'` is my string,
`'20'` is my variable, and I want to remove everything before 20.

Comment: If you provide sample input and expected output, the question would be more clear and you are more likely to get a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps [`.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) suits this better than `.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s1 = '5+5 20-5 5.4 50/2'
s2 = '20'

new_s1 = s2 + s1.split(s2, 1)[1]
```

Result:

```
'20-5 5.4 50/2'
```

This relies on the fact that s2 is in fact contained in s1.

Just be aware that using `str.split()` is definitely not the best approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.partition()`:

```py
before, sep, after = '5+5 20-5 5.4 50/2'.partition('20')

print(before) # -> '5+5 '

print(sep) # -> '20'

print(after) # -> '-5 5.4 50/2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using string slicing and the index function:

```py
s1 = '5+5 20-5 5.4 50/2'
s2 = '20'

# returns the resulting string or s1 if s2 not found in s1
print(s1[s1.index(s2):] if s2 in s1 else s1)

# result:
20-5 5.4 50/2
```